# Angular $watchCollection old value is not updated properly for multiple updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have an html file which has 3 check box values

```
<input type="checkbox"ng-model="checkbox-1"/>
<input type="checkbox"ng-model="checkbox-2"/>
<input type="checkbox"ng-model="checkbox-3"/>
```

and there is a watchCollection defined in the controller where it will be triggered when a checkbox status is changed

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['checkbox-1', 'checkbox-2', 'checkbox-3'], function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('checkbox-1: new - ' + newValue[0] + ' old - ' + oldValue[0]);
    console.log('checkbox-1: new - ' + newValue[1] + ' old - ' + oldValue[1]);
    console.log('checkbox-1: new - ' + newValue[2] + ' old - ' + oldValue[2]);
  });
```

But when the checkboc values are updated again and again, the old value list of the $watchCollection is not updated properly and it keep populated with the old values.

e.g.

- all check boxes are un-tick initially
- tick on the 1st checkbox -> **oldValue = [false, false, false], newValue = [true, false, false]**
- tick the 2nd checkbox now -> **oldvalue = [false, false, false], newValue = [true, true, false]**

In the old value list, the first value should be true since we changed it in the first operation to true. But its still the initial one

I know i can resolve this by updating the check box variables with a model value and adding a watch for model. Would be great anyone have any ideas to resolve this using the $watchCollection approach ?

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/a0h5nujo/

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle or a working snippet where i can test?

Comment: updated the JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/a0h5nujo/

Comment: @SameeraSM I don't see any problem. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an identified issue in angular 1.6 and they will fix this with the 1.7 release

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/16392#issuecomment-355843405

Answer (score 1):

try adding this:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['checkbox-1', 'checkbox-2', 'checkbox-3'], function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('checkbox-1: new - ' + newValue[0] + ' old - ' + oldValue[0]);
    console.log('checkbox-1: new - ' + newValue[1] + ' old - ' + oldValue[1]);
    console.log('checkbox-1: new - ' + newValue[2] + ' old - ' + oldValue[2]);
  },true);


",true)
```

if u want to deeply understand how it's works read this:

https://medium.com/@jbmilgrom/watch-watchgroup-watchcollection-and-deep-watching-in-angularjs-6390f23508fe

**Update:**
https://jsfiddle.net/molikh/a0h5nujo/7/

Comment: i have updated fiddle for u, https://jsfiddle.net/molikh/a0h5nujo/4/   ,it's working

Comment: i think your question is wrong at the first, you first change value1 then u change value2 why do u think the old value of first one should be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div ng-app="valueList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkBoxes.checkbox1"/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkBoxes.checkbox2"/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkBoxes.checkbox3"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("valueList", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.checkBoxes = {};

    $scope.$watchGroup(['checkBoxes.checkbox1', 'checkBoxes.checkbox2', 'checkBoxes.checkbox3'], function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('=======================');
    console.log('checkbox-1: old - ' + oldValue[0] + ' ,new - ' + newValue[0]);
    console.log('checkbox-1: old - ' + oldValue[1] + ' ,new - ' + newValue[1]);
    console.log('checkbox-1: old - ' + oldValue[2] + ' ,new - ' + newValue[2]);
  });
});
```